# Python Cloudscraper dont parse on Background

Tags: python, ubuntu, screen, tmux

Python Cloudscraper dont parse on Background

I try using:

- screen
- nohub
- tmux
- I try to add it on ubuntu service

Work only when i run without any backgrounds. How could i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found how i fix. Just add ssl_context and set two arguments into tuple (fullchain.pem, privkey.pem) - which i get from certbot